# Two column Dropdown for WordPress Toolbar

Tags: css

This started out as something seeming 'easy' but I'm stumped. I've created a plugin which removes all of the nodes from the WordPress Toolbar then adds three new parent nodes. One of the parent nodes has 20 child nodes. I'd like the child nodes to be in two columns and not the default single column.

For example, let's say id of your-news-feed and another id of conversations are to be in the second column. The below CSS gets them to the right but dropped below the others. There challenge is the lack of multiple divs to use CSS, and only the li list itself.

```
li#wp-admin-bar-your-news-feed {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left:150px;
}

li#wp-admin-bar-conversations {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left:150px;
}
```

Just in case it is needed, here is the relevant PHP code for the parent and child nodes.

```
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

            // Alerts
            $alerts = array(
                'id'    => 'alerts-unread',
                'title' => 'Alerts',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink( '/account/alerts' )
            );

            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( $alerts );

            // Inbox
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'xf-inbox',
                'title' => __( 'Inbox' ),
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink( '/conversations' )
            ) );

            // Add username as a parent to the WordPress Toolbar
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'display-username',
                'title' => $visitor['username']
            ) );

            // Add Personal Details
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'personal-details',
                'title' => __( 'Personal Details' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/personal-details')
            ) );

            // Add Signature
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'signature',
                'title' => __( 'Signature' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/signature')
            ) );

            // Add Contact Details
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'contact-details',
                'title' => __( 'Contact Details' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/contact-details')
            ) );

            // Add Privacy
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'privacy',
                'title' => __( 'Privacy' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/privacy')
            ) );

            // Add Preferences
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'preferences',
                'title' => __( 'Preferences' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/preferences')
            ) );

            // Add Alert Preferences
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'alert-preferences',
                'title' => __( 'Alert Preferences' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/alert-preferences')
            ) );

            // Add Avatar
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'avatar',
                'title' => __( 'Avatar' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/avatar')
            ) );

            // Add Security
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'security',
                'title' => __( 'Password' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/security')
            ) );

            // Second Column

            // Add Your News Feed
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'your-news-feed',
                'title' => __( 'Your News Feed' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/news-feed')
            ) );

            // Add Conversations
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'conversations',
                'title' => __( 'Conversations' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('/conversations')
            ) );

            // Add Alerts
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'sub-alerts',
                'title' => __( 'Alerts' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/alerts')
            ) );

            // Add Like's You've Received
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'sub-likes',
                'title' => __( 'Likes You\'ve Received' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/likes')
            ) );

            // Add Your Content
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'sub-your-content',
                'title' => __( 'Your Content' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('search/member') . '?user_id=' . $visitor['user_id']
            ) );

            // Add People You Follow
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'people-you-follow',
                'title' => __( 'People You Follow' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/following')
            ) );

            // Add People You Ignore
            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'people-you-ignore',
                'title' => __( 'People You Ignore' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink('account/ignored')
            ) );

            // Add Logout to parent 'display username'
            $logout_url = XenWord::getBoardUrl() . '/' . XenForo_Link::buildPublicLink( 'logout',
                    $visitor, array(
                        '_xfToken' => $visitor['csrf_token_page'],
                        'redirect' => $redirect
                    ) );

            $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array(
                'id'    => 'xf-logout',
                'title' => __( 'Log Out' ),
                'parent' => 'display-username',
                'href'  => $logout_url
            ) );

        }
```

I apologize if this seems obvious (and Googling) but after fussing for some time, the possibility of two columns escapes me. Am I missing another place to widen the drop down first?